# Can't find ng2-typeahead in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, bootstrap-typeahead

I want to use the ng2-typeahead autocomplete component.

For the use I did the same instruction as shown [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-typeahead).

If I start my application I got this error at the beginning in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:9001/ng2-typeahead 404 (Not Found)
Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found ) load (index):42
```

I really just copied the code and installed typeahead. I did not found any configuration for the systemjs.config

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: are you using angular2-cli or official angular2 docs for setting up the project?

Comment: I am using the offical angular 2 (client side)

Comment: I also tried with an entry in the map block:  'ng2-typeahead':     'node_modules/ng2-typeahead'. It is still not working